# Problem with LVM over mdadm with NTFS. Is it possible?

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, lvm, mdadm

I am a bit of a linux newbie, and i have come across an error that i dont really know how to troubleshoot.

my idea is to cram 6TiB drives into a box, make three sets of raid1, then stretch a logical volume over the three raided sets. then make a samba share with an NTFS filesystem for a neat fileserver for a small production environment.

here is my error:

```
user@FSrv:~$ sudo mount /dev/box1/Recordings /rec -t ntfs
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/mapper/box1-Recordings': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/mapper/box1-Recordings' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
user@FSrv:~$
```

here is lsblk:

```
user@FSrv:~$ sudo lsblk 
NAME                       MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                          8:0    0  29.8G  0 disk  
├─sda1                       8:1    0   243M  0 part  /boot
├─sda2                       8:2    0     1K  0 part  
└─sda5                       8:5    0  29.6G  0 part  
  ├─box1-root (dm-0)       252:0    0  15.8G  0 lvm   /
  ├─box1-swap_1 (dm-1)     252:1    0   7.9G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
  └─box1-Recordings (dm-2) 252:2    0   2.7T  0 lvm   
sdb                          8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk  
└─md0                        9:0    0 931.4G  0 raid1 
  └─box1-Recordings (dm-2) 252:2    0   2.7T  0 lvm   
sdc                          8:32   0 931.5G  0 disk  
└─md0                        9:0    0 931.4G  0 raid1 
  └─box1-Recordings (dm-2) 252:2    0   2.7T  0 lvm   
sdd                          8:48   0 931.5G  0 disk  
└─md1                        9:1    0 931.4G  0 raid1 
  └─box1-Recordings (dm-2) 252:2    0   2.7T  0 lvm   
sde                          8:64   0 931.5G  0 disk  
└─md1                        9:1    0 931.4G  0 raid1 
  └─box1-Recordings (dm-2) 252:2    0   2.7T  0 lvm   
sdf                          8:80   0 931.5G  0 disk  
└─md2                        9:2    0 931.4G  0 raid1 
  └─box1-Recordings (dm-2) 252:2    0   2.7T  0 lvm   
sdg                          8:96   0 931.5G  0 disk  
└─md2                        9:2    0 931.4G  0 raid1 
  └─box1-Recordings (dm-2) 252:2    0   2.7T  0 lvm   
user@FSrv:~$
```

here is `fdisk -l` : http://paste.ubuntu.com/1623016/

Here is `pvdisplay`, `vgdisplay`, and `lvdisplay`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1623019/

Does anyone know what the root cause would be? Or what my next troubleshooting step would be?

Comment: Did you create a filesystem on these partitions? See `man mkfs.ntfs`.

Comment: @Martin, that was the solution to my problem! A small oversight, but a world of difference. It didn't even occur to me that I needed to do that, so thank you!!

Comment: Why NTFS? You'll not be able to read this filesystem on other operating systems anyway as you're using LVM (and software RAID).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have not created a filesystem on the partitions; see `man mkfs.ntfs`. Just setting the partition type is not enough.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. i would upvote, but i need 15 points total to upvote.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you don't want to use NTFS unless you are dual booting with Windows.  For sharing files with samba to Windows or other clients, you are better off using a normal filesystem like ext4.

Second, you are better off with a single raid array than letting lvm stripe over multiple raid1s.  A raid5 or 6 will give you the most usable space with good performance.  The raid6 can handle two disks failing without data loss.  A raid10 will give the same space as what you proposed, but better performance.  You should use the offset or far layout depending on whether you want to optimize for writes or reads.

Comment: my decision for ntfs is arbitrary, it wouldnt let me do ext3 or ext4 or anything else. you have not provided a solution to my problem, thank you for your input though!

Comment: @Ace, you contradict yourself.  Either you chose ntfs arbitrarily, or you had to because there was no other choice.  Which is it?

Comment: which one would you prefer?